# Dynamic formatted string from another function

Tags: c, string, dynamic, char

I have a function A with a body like so

```
char* A (const char* arg) {
    char ret[8192];
    B(ret);
    return strdup(ret);
}
```

Function B looks like this (some pseudo code on iteration logic for brevity)

```
void B(char* ret) {
    char retString[8192];

    while(ITERATIONS_LEFT) {
        snprintf(returnString, 8192, "\n Format %s\n\n", IT_VALUE);
        snprintf(returnString, 8192, "\n Val %s\n\n", IT_VALUE_2);
    }

    strcpy(ret, returnString);
}
```

So essentially I have a function A that gives another function B a string buffer for B to enter formatted data into. Now this works fine as long as the total data returned from the iterations does not exceed 8196 (just a guess at a 'sufficiently large' value) but I think it would be better if I could do this dynamically and not have to worry about the case where my buffer fills. How would I achieve this in a fairly efficient manner, with the constraints that function A must still call function B, and that B's signature can be changed but A's cannot?

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but you are freeing the memory allocated by the `A` function?

Comment: To use dynamic memory (`malloc`) you need to know the size beforehand (calculate it using `strlen("LITERALS") + strlen(values) + 1`)

Comment: More related to your problem, from [this `snprintf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf): "Calling snprintf with zero bufsz and null pointer for buffer is useful to determine the necessary buffer size to contain the output", with an example following.

Comment: Yes the memory in A is freed. I guess the key problem is the fact I will not know the size of the resultant string until the iterations have been completed, however while performing the iterations I wish to grab the data and format it appropriately (so I won't have a buffer of appropriate size to deal with my iteration code until I have finished iterating), so the question is where do I put that data? I could always iterate twice but I would like to avoid that for obvious reasons

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your allocation problem, you overwrite the same string here:

```
    snprintf(returnString, 8192, "\n Format %s\n\n", IT_VALUE);
    snprintf(returnString, 8192, "\n Val %s\n\n", IT_VALUE_2);
```

You could solve this with a kind of "appender" that re-allocates memory as it is needed by determining the required length by passing a size of 0 to `snprintf` as Joachim Pileborg suggested:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct append_t {
    char *str;          /* string */
    size_t len;         /* length of string */
    size_t size;        /* allocated size */
};

void append(struct append_t *app, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    size_t len;

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    while (app->len + len + 1 >= app->size) {
        app->size = app->size ? app->size * 2 : 0x100;
        app->str = realloc(app->str, app->size);
        // Check and handle error
    }

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    len = vsnprintf(app->str + app->len, app->size - app->len, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    app->len += len;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct append_t app = {NULL};

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (i > 1) append(&app, ", ");
        append(&app, "'%s'", argv[i]);
    }

    if (app.str) puts(app.str);

    free(app.str);
    return 0;
}
```

Things to note:

- The code uses the fact that `realloc(NULL, size)` behaves like `malloc(size)`. The appender must be initialised to all zero.
- `vsnprintf` is a variant of `snprintf` that takes a `va_list` instead of variadic arguments. The `v...printf` functions allow you to write your own `printf`-like functions. You can't pass variadic arguments to other functions, you have to create a `va_list` with the `va_...` macros from the `<stdarg.h>` header.
- Most compilers can detect mismatches between printing formats and arguments for the standard `printf` functions. If you wat to benefit from these checks for your function, you could use the appropriate GCC attributes `((format(printf, 2, 3))` or the SAL annotation `_Printf_format_string_`.

In your example, `A` would create the appender and pass it to `B` and then return its `.str`. You could also return an appender from `B` and return its `.str`from `A`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following versions of `A` and `B`.

```
char* A (const char* arg) {
    int size = 8192;
    char *ret = malloc(size);
    B(ret, size);
    return ret;
}

void B(char* ret, int size) {
    int pos = 0, required;

    while(ITERATIONS_LEFT) {
        required = snprintf(NULL, 0, "\n Format %s\n\n", IT_VALUE);
        if (pos + required >= size) {
            size *= 2;
            ret = realloc(ret, size);
        }
        pos += sprintf(ret + pos, "\n Format %s\n\n", IT_VALUE);

        required = snprintf(NULL, 0, "\n Val %s\n\n", IT_VALUE_2);
        if (pos + required >= size) {
            size *= 2;
            ret = realloc(ret, size);
        }
        pos += sprintf(ret + pos, "\n Val %s\n\n", IT_VALUE_2);
    }
}
```

Note that:

1. buffer size is doubled if it isn't enough. That works well in most cases.
2. copying is minimized (no `strdup` or `strcpy`)
3. you may want to make a new function with the repeated code in the while loop
4. In your version of B buffer is overwritten each time you call `snprintf`. Here the writing position (`pos`) is updated to append (null terminating `char` overwritten)
5. `snprintf` with `NULL` argument will return the required buffer size without printing anything anywhere
6. You may want to check that `ret` is not `NULL` after calling `realloc`
7. If `ret` is not `NULL` it's certain that the buffer is large enough. Thus simple `sprintf` is used to actually print.
8. Remember to `free` the buffer!
9. I haven't tested the code myself